# creating instagram posts (video and photos) on behalf of users server side Scheduled

Tags: api, sdk, instagram, social-media

I wanted to create video or picture posts on behalf of an authenticated user (i have their access token after they logged in to my using instagram credentials) on a future time.

For example, user creates a video post tonight, and schedules it to be posted tomorrow at 7AM. 
Is this possible?

I know there are companies out there like hootsuite that claim to allow to schedule posts for social media account but i've never used them and i want to create  cloud service, so an SDK or API is what I'm looking for.

Their developer portal is very vague so i wanted to ask the community for some direction.

Facebook (owns instagram) has documentation on how to share feed post from your app to instagram, but it still requires the instagram app to open and for the user to tap/click the submit button.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/

any insights in the right direction is appreciated.